# PHP Shell Exec Infinite Loop

Tags: php, loops, exec, shell-exec

**Server Info:**
CentOS 6.8 (Final)
Plesk Panel 12.5
PHP 5.3.3

i run in php file:

```
sleep(1);
shell_exec("php index.php > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &");
```

Constantly working but, stops after a certain period of time.
How can i run Infinite?

Comment: *why* exactly would you want to do that?

Comment: maybe **nohup** can help ... nohup php index.php > ...